# gridview row click conflict with checkbox

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkbox, onclick

I have a gridview and I add a click event to row click:

```
protected void gvProject_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowIndex != -1)
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(gvProject, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
}
```

my problem is with check box in gridview, I don't want row click event fire when I check/uncheck my checkbox. how can I do this? I search but I not found anything...

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution:

I change my rowdatabound event to this:

```
if (e.Row.RowIndex != -1)
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
                if (i != 0)
                    e.Row.Cells[i].Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(gvProject, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
```

this code skip checkbox cell.